# How do you add backgroundImage to div in react component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm following the 'build rpg game using react' tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZcNGfcn-oo&t=572sa and simply typing what the presenter does.

I'm trying to add a background image to a div in the following. Why am I keep getting an Unexpected token error at backgroundimage?
import Unicorn from './Unicorn.png';

```
class Player extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div
         style={{
              position:'absolute',
              top: props.position[1],
              left: props.position[0],
              backgroundImage: 'url('${Unicorn})',
              backgroundPosition: '0 0',
              width:'32px',
              height:'32px'
         }}
      />
      )
    }
    
    mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
        return{
            ...state.Player,
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `'url('${Unicorn})'` is missing a quotation, also you need to replace the quotation ' with tildas ` to let js know that the string is a string literal.  try replacing it with `'url(tilda${Unicorn}tilda)'`

Comment: backgroundImage: \`url(${Unicorn})\`. Change the single quote with back tick.

Comment: This is hard to explain in the comments because anything between two ` characters are treated as code blocks lol

Comment: \`ab\` trying back tick.

Comment: @MEnf-that worked! I did not recognize that as a tilde. I spent hours on this! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Replace single quote with tilde key <kbd>`</kbd>: (located below <kbd>ESC</kbd> key)

```
backgroundImage: `url(${Unicorn})`,
```

Or, with the quote:

```
backgroundImage: 'url('+Unicorn+')',
```

---

Also, be sure to use `backgroundRepeat`, without it, the background will be repeated by default: (BTW, you may not see the repeated background due to its width and height constraints)

```
backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
```